# Problem with Debian 10, Eclipse, C when linking GTK3 libs

Tags: eclipse, linker, gtk3

I am using Debian 10, GTK3 (package libgtk-3-dev), CDT, GCC. Compiling and linking by command line / shell ($1-parameter) works fine:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` $1.c -o $1 `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I installed Codeblocks and changed the compiler and linker settings due to command line options, it works as well.

But I want to use Eclipse (2019-03) as IDE as I am used to it.
Installation of pkg-config plugin via Marketplace failed (compatibilty problem).
So I changed compiler and linker settings, replacing pkg-config (didn't work) with its contents.

Compiler settings:

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Linker settings:

```
-lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void on_button_clicked (GtkButton *button) {
  g_print ("button '%s' clicked\n", gtk_button_get_label (button));
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkWidget *window, *button;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hallo Michel");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);

  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_button_clicked), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation works (.o-file created), debugging is possible, but linking fails:

Eclipse Console output:

```
Building target: GTK3
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -o "GTK3"  ./gtk_test.o   
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:31: GTK3] Fehler 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Eclipse  Problems output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':    GTK3            C/C++ Problem
make: *** [makefile:31: GTK3] Fehler 1  GTK3            C/C++ Problem
Type 'GTK_CONTAINER (window)' could not be resolved gtk_test.c  /GTK3   line 14 Semantic Error
Type 'GTK_CONTAINER (window)' could not be resolved gtk_test.c  /GTK3   line 17 Semantic Error
Type 'GTK_WINDOW (window)' could not be resolved    gtk_test.c  /GTK3   line 13 Semantic Error
undefined reference to `main'   GTK3            C/C++ Problem
```

Who knows what to do?

Thanks in advance
Michel

Comment: How is debugging possible if you are not able to link your code into an executable?

Comment: I can't answer this question. These are the Eclipse "Debug-directory" contents: gtk_test.d  gtk_test.o makefile  objects.mk  sources.mk  subdir.mk. And there isn't any executable otherwhere